# Filtering news posts with a dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, filter, sharepoint-news

I want to be able to filter news posts based on custom meta data, using a dropdown. I want *all* news posts to display in a list by default, but be able to choose a category from a dropdown and then have it display only news posts with that category. How can I do this?

I have looked at creating an add-in to pull the metadata and create this, but I feel like there must be an easier way that does not require code changes. I think it is possible to filter a list, but I am not even sure how to get my news posts to be in a list collection.

Answer (score 0):

[All your news posts are stored in the Pages library of your site.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-share-news-on-your-sharepoint-sites-495f8f1a-3bef-4045-b33a-55e5abe7aed7#bkmk_createpage)

To see a list of all your news posts, See all in the upper right of the news section on the published page.

[image]

You could also edit the **[News web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-news-web-part-on-a-sharepoint-page-c2dcee50-f5d7-434b-8cb9-a7feefd9f165#bkmk_sitenews)** to make it layout as list and add custom metadata as page properties, then filter with [page properties](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-edit-and-add-page-details-778018d3-8269-4fd2-a55d-8c0e5b72b938):

[image][image]

**--------------------------------------Update----------------------------------------**

As picture shown, in the filter panel,you could select property name with a dropdown list (equals/Doesn't equal/Begins with/Contains) property value to filter the display list.

However, we could not use property value as a dropdown list, it's necessary to enter the value manually.

[image]

Comment: I don't have an option for "Page Properties" in the News webpart filter dropdown, despite having custom metadata on pages.

Comment: Okay, I've figured out the Page Properties not displaying. Now, how would I allow the user to toggle that filter using a dropdown?

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check it.

Comment: So, I understand that you are configuring the filter with a dropdown in the settings. What I am looking for is a dropdown widget to display on the actual rendered page, which the user of the sharepoint site can use to filter what news is displayed for them on the page.

Comment: Currently there is not possible unless you edit the news web part.

Comment: How would I edit the news web part to do this? I am happy to edit the code for it if that is possible.

Comment: There is no custom code available, you need to use spfx to develop custom news web parts yourself.https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview